# There is an error when making modal window by redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I'm trying to make login page by modal window. I tried to connect components by redux but there is an error so it doesn't work. I created reducer and used dispatch at login button component. If I press this button, the login modal window will appear. and I used useselector at another component to show login component. It says there is an error called 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isClick')'. But don't know how to fix it. I'd really appreciate it if you let me know. Thanks!!

this is index.js file. This file is rootreducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import goodsReducer from "./counter";
import loginClick from "./loginClick";


const rootRudcer = combineReducers(
  {
    goodsReducer,
    loginClick
  }
)

export default rootRudcer;
```

and this file is loginClick.jsx file. This is reducer I'm going to use. I made two actions. One returns true when the button is pressed, and the other action returns false. I think I might be wrong about the way I use it here

```
export const yesClick = () => {
  return{
    type : 'Yes',
  }
} 

export const noClick = () => {
  return{
    type : 'No',
  }
} 

const initialState = {
  isClick : false
}

const loginClick = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "Yes" :
      return {
        ...state,
        isClick : true
      }

    case "No" :
      return {
        ...state,
        isClick : false
      }

    default :
      return {
        ...state,
      }  
  }
}

export default loginClick;
```

this file is NaviRight.jsx file. There is a login button in this file and I used dispatch here to return true when the button is clicked. I think you just need to check the part where the dispatch was used. I erased useless css code in this.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import '../navi.css';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const Login = styled.div`
  
`

const Regi = styled.div`
 
`


function NaviRight() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div id='NaviRight'>
      <Login onClick={()=>{dispatch({type:"Yes"})}}>
        login
      </Login >
      <Regi>
        회원가입
      </Regi>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NaviRight;
```

And finally this is SiteHomepage.jsx file. I used useselector in this file so I can show login modal page if 'loginButton' is true

```
import React from 'react';
import Top from './Header/Top';
import Navi from './Header/Navi/Navi';
import Body from './Body/Body';
import Footer from './Footer/Footer';
import NaviRight from './Header/Navi/Components/NaviRight';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Login1 from './Login/Login1';


function SiteHomepage (props) {

  const loginButton = useSelector(state => state.loginClick.isClick);

  return (
    <>
      {loginButton&&Login1}
      <Top />
      <Navi />
      <Body />
      <Footer />
    </>  
  );
}


export default SiteHomepage;
```

I already checked there is no problem at login component and redux store so I'll skip it

[image: error]

Comment: I think the there is a mismatch in the action types. In the actions you have defined it in uppercase ("YES", "NO"), but you in the reducer switch you are not checking for the uppercase type ("Yes", "No"). Hope you got it.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know, but I think there are still other errors

Comment: Is there any possibility you can post the screenshot of the error?

Comment: I added error image. Hope it helps

Comment: This Login1 is a react component right? You cannot use react components like that. You have to use it like <Login1 />. So it should be {loginButton && <Login1/>}

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a very small problem. Thanks for your kindness. It helped me a lot. Now it works very well